# Compress and Extract options in Thunar

Tags: 14.04, customization, filemanager, thunar

Please anyone help me in creating Custom Options for **Compress** and **Extract Here** in **Thunar File manager**

Please help me...

Answer (score 23):

No need to create custom options: you just need to install the [`thunar-archive-plugin`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=thunar-archive-plugin&searchon=names) to have both **Compress** and **Extract Here** options.

You may install it with the following command:

```
 sudo apt-get install thunar-archive-plugin
```

After installing (and closing all previous instances of Thunar), you will find both options in Thunar's right-click menu.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/532162/198486)

Comment: Nice! I especially like that it's at the top menu level.

Comment: Im starting to love thunar

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions

It has step by step instructions including compress/extraction examples.

Comment: @user275472: As you've never accepted any answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...