# Extract here option and Source code for Thunar File manager

Tags: filemanager, archive, thunar, file-roller, thunar-custom-actions

Please anyone can paste me the source code for **Extract Here** option in Thunar File Manager.
Any type of script i.e Python OR Shell Script OR PHP is OK.

Please help me

Answer (score 9):

You need to install [`thunar-archive-plugin`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/thunar-archive-plugin) to use **Extract Here** option.

Install it using

```
 sudo apt-get install thunar-archive-plugin
```

Once installed, you can find this option in Right click context menu.

If you want to use some custom action in your thunar menu, you can see [here](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions) for how to configure this.

Answer (score 1):

As helpful as the current top answer is, it doesn't actually answer the original question, so for whoever's looking for the source code, here's the answer to that.

The plugin is written in C. The source code can be found here:

https://git.xfce.org/thunar-plugins/thunar-archive-plugin

Github mirror:
https://github.com/xfce-mirror/thunar-archive-plugin